# Liability insurance claim

Tags: germany, rental, insurance

I recently moved out of a rented apartment.
My previous landlord asked me that because of my use the bathroom doors were damaged .
as a result I need to pay for it .Since I had liability insurance I requested for a claim but the insurance company rejected saying it comes under normal wear and tear .

This is an excessive use of the living space. A claim on the leased property is excessive if it exceeds that for the individual Room agreed or the usual measure (§ 538 BGB) .§ 538 BGB wear and tear of the rented property through contractual use The lessee is not responsible for changes or deterioration of the rented property caused by the contractual use

Any idea what should I do in that case.
Do I have to pay to landlord by myself .

So my question is basically if I am liable than liability insurance should cover if not then landowner should not ask .

Comment: Yes. Why would you not have to pay for it? Assuming your tenancy agreement states you are liable for damage, and you don’t dispute that you caused the damage, of course

Comment: @Traveller but liability insurance says it should This is an excessive use of the living space.
A claim on the leased property is excessive if it exceeds that for the individual
Room agreed or the usual measure (§ 538 BGB) .§ 538 BGB wear and tear of the rented property through contractual use
The lessee is not responsible for changes or deterioration of the rented property caused by the contractual use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated the type and extent of the damage, and how much the landlord is asking you to pay. Do you agree that you damaged the door? What does your tenancy agreement state regarding your responsibilities? Insurance typically won’t cover you for *everything*, if your lease says you’re liable you will have to pay the landlord and then dispute the rejected claim with your insurance company, IMHO. Your question might be better on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: extent was there were some minor scratch to the paint but my owner says to change the door :) .

Comment: @HariomSingh liability may not cover normal wear and tear, but your landlord will still ask. If you believe this is normal wear and tear tell them to go fly a kite. If they don't return the deposit - take legal action. I'm sure there are more than enough renter protection agencies in Germany to talk to.

Comment: Replacing a door is not a reasonable remedy for a scratched paint.  Repainting the door is the more reasonable remedy.  Whether the scratches fall under normal wear and tear is another matter, as is the degree to which normal wear and tear is the tenant's responsibility; these will depend on the terms of the lease and on local law.

Comment: Normal wear and tear is indeed not expected to be covered by you. As far as I understood, your landlord claims that it was damaged beyond normal wear and tear, and your insurance claims it was normal wear and tear. Probably this case will be hard to solve without a lawyer advice then.